# What’s the proper word to describe this?

Tags: single-word-requests

Do you know what word I can use to describe a situation where you cry while reading a letter then your tears dropped to the paper and unfortunately, since that letter is a printed one, some parts of the letter are gone/got blurred?
Anyway, it’s the act of the tears wiping out the parts of the paper that I’m talking about.

Comment: Actually, any kind of moisture 

Comment: The phrase 'blotted with tears' is sometimes used to describe a letter in this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single word that means something removed by water is *dissolved*.

> The words on the page dissolved in my tears.

Comment: AAAAAAAA IT’S THAT WORD!!! THANK YOU SO MUCHHH

Comment: @Agnes - How about you give it the green checkmark to show that that was the answer you were hoping for?

Comment: @aparente001 I will ^^ but I’m just waiting, just in case there are still people who want to leave an answer here.

Comment: @Agnes - I see.  Well, I guess you could also say that the letters started to swim or melt.

Comment: @aparente001 Thank you so much for telling me that!